# Java, Base64: How to write a Base64OutputStream class using Decorator Pattern

Tags: java, base64, decorator

Based on my original [question about RSA and Base64 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834667/rsa-and-base64-encoding-too-many-bytes) and the comments there I am wondering what is the best approach to write a Base64OutputStream (or Input Stream). I originally had called it Base64PrintWriter and extended it from PrintWriter passing a PrintWriter to the Constructor.

```
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64;

public class Base64OutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {

    public Base64OutputStream(OutputStream out) {
        super(out);
    }

    public void write(byte[] decodedBytes) throws IOException {
        byte[] base64Message = Base64.encode(decodedBytes);
        super.write(base64Message);
    }

    public void writeln(byte[] decodedBytes) throws IOException {
        write(decodedBytes);
        super.write("\n".getBytes());
        super.flush();
    }
}
```

I changed my original implementation to the one above and I initialize it with:

```
Base64OutputStream base64encoder = new Base64OutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
```

My questions are:

1. Is this a good design?
2. Can it be done better?
3. Have I applied the decorator pattern correctly.
4. Is it good to extend FilteredOutputStream instead of OutputStream? [Oracle](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Streams/WritingIOSC/) indicates it is good but are there any disadvantages or reasons to still extend from OutputStream?
5. And should I additionally decorate it with BufferedOutputStream when I call the constructor?

Comment: Hi lanoxx, you asked me to to comment on the design in your other question. As I said, I personally would rather have a Writer
as parent (for the encoder) as it makes it harder to make character encoding mistakes (e.g. when writing to a stream containing UTF-16 characters). Otherwise, I would advise you to take a look at Brent Wordens answer and copy the Apache interface (e.g. line break handling). One thing that is sorely lacking from that is proper exception handling, you might want to get around that. If you want I can paste an state based implementation for Java 1.5 or higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are amenable to using open source, you can look at [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec).  It contains a [Base64OutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/codec/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64OutputStream.html) that should meet you needs.

Comment: Thanks, I had a look there, also this does not exactly answer all my questions the code is useful. However I dont understand why they override so much methods.

Comment: @lanoxx The reason there are more overridden methods than in yours is because the problem isn't as simple as encoding the bytes as given.  For instance, with yours os.write("ab".getBytes()); os.write("cd".getBytes());  produces different output than os.write("abcd".getBytes());

Answer (score 0):

As far as your implementation of the Decorator Design Pattern goes, I think you're missing a crucial part. I could be mistaking but the way I've learned the Decorator Pattern in school it needs to allow dynamic behavior addition and it also creates an abstraction layer between your interface and newly added class.

I see you're adding the 'writeln()' method to your newly created class, but that's a simple method addition and itself doesn't constitute the basis of the Decorator DP.

What the Decorator DP wants you to do is to create an abstraction layer, a decorator (which is usually an abstract class). And that decorator will become the parent of your new class(es), in your case Base64OutputStream would become the child of the said Decorator.

Design Patterns are there in order to solve conception problems that you might encounter, from what I understand, adding the Decorator Pattern to your application wouldn't benefit you a whole lot. But then again I don't know what you're trying to accomplish in the grand scheme of things.

Here's a site I find helpful when trying to model applications for school work, perhaps you've already stumbled upon it, it explains the Decorator pattern quite well, it also includes valuable examples of possible implementation: http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternDecorator.aspx.

Hope this answers your 3rd question and good luck! :)