# Store 3DES in String instead of CipherOutputStream

Tags: java, encryption, 3des

I'm trying to 3DES encrypt a string and store it in a properties file using [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/TripleDES.htm).  The problem I'm having is I do not want to write the contents of encrypt() and decrypt() to a file directly from the methods.  I want to store it in a string for use later.

Below are the methods I'm using.

As you can see this uses CipherOutputStream and CipherInputStream.  How would I read the result of both encrypt() and decrypt() into a String instead of writing it out to file?

```
  public static void encrypt(SecretKey key, InputStream in, OutputStream out)
      throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException,
      NoSuchPaddingException, IOException {
    // Create and initialize the encryption engine
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

    // Create a special output stream to do the work for us
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(out, cipher);

    // Read from the input and write to the encrypting output stream
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
      cos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    cos.close();

    // For extra security, don't leave any plaintext hanging around memory.
    java.util.Arrays.fill(buffer, (byte) 0);
  }

  /**
   * Use the specified TripleDES key to decrypt bytes ready from the input
   * stream and write them to the output stream. This method uses uses Cipher
   * directly to show how it can be done without CipherInputStream and
   * CipherOutputStream.
   */
  public static void decrypt(SecretKey key, InputStream in, OutputStream out)
      throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, IOException,
      IllegalBlockSizeException, NoSuchPaddingException,
      BadPaddingException {
    // Create and initialize the decryption engine
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

    // Read bytes, decrypt, and write them out.
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
      out.write(cipher.update(buffer, 0, bytesRead));
    }

    // Write out the final bunch of decrypted bytes
    out.write(cipher.doFinal());
    out.flush();
  }
```

Comment: I would have up voted it sooner but I was flipping between screens.  But since you asked the question:  Even though what you said is straight forward a code example for others who might come across the question who are n00bs is always a good idea.

Comment: I know. But it is already late, and I dont have an IDE around here. And I try to avoid putting up code without having it compiled lately. But beyond that: a noob that can't figure how to create these objects and stack them together ... has probably other things to learn as well;-)

Comment: It is probably better I didnt put up code. I would swear by oath I upvoted your question already. No ... I didnt.

Comment: Simple and too the point btw, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple: instead of passing a file output stream to these methods - pass a different kind of stream, for example a ByteArrayOutputStream.

Then you can extract the encrypted data as string from that stream.

And to ensure that the final result is reasonable encoded, you should actually use some kind of [Base64OutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896237/java-base64-how-to-write-a-base64outputstream-class-using-decorator-pattern) which in turn writes to that [ByteArrayOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html).